# Screen Saver's Wait Setting is Greyed Out

Tags: windows-7, screensaver

I have admin rights on my laptop but in the screen saver settings it is set that the screen saver appears after 15 minutes of inactivity. this setting is greyed out and I can not change it so that the screen saver does not appear after 15 minutes.

can somebody recommend how to change it so that this setting is not greyed out and I can change it so that screen saver does not appear.

Thank you,
Irina

Comment: Is this computer on a domain? If it is, you need your admin to change the group policy regarding your screensaver.

Comment: Check that the laptop does not have a manufacturer's utility installed to manage settings. These can override the control panel screensaver and power settings.

Answer (score 2):

If your sytem is not connected to a domain, then try this:

Start `Regedit.exe` and goto:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Control Panel\Desktop
```

Delete these values in the right-pane:

- SCRNSAVE.EXE
- ScreenSaverIsSecure
- ScreenSaveTimeout

Repeat the same here, if the key/values are present:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Control Panel\Desktop
```

Logoff and login back.

If you've used the Local Group Policy Editor to configure ScreenSaver Policy, you need to reverse the settings there instead of Regedit.exe